# Not able to upload file using django-filer django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and trying to migrate one old python project. In one module while i am trying to upload file it is throwing below error:

```
KeyError: '32'
  File "django/core/handlers/base.py", line 112, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 57, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "filer/admin/clipboardadmin.py", line 88, in ajax_upload
    'thumbnail': file_obj.icons['32'],
```

## Version

Django==1.6.8
easy-thumbnails==2.2
django-filer==0.9.4

So how to fix it?

Comment: It raised a `KeyError`, meaning it tried to request `'32'` from a dictionary, but the key was not found. So probably `file_obj.icons['32']` didn't exist. You could try posting some code where you are trying to access it. It might be an issue with the package itself.

Comment: here is the https://codepen.io/dhavalsisodiya/pen/oqbVyY which has a code which is in clipboardadmin.py file

Comment: You could try checking what keys are in the `file_obj` variable, because for some reason it doesn't exist.